# Reverting the selection of JCombox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, itemlistener

We are trying to implement a validation on the selections made with a `JCombobox`. In case of the new selection failing this validation, we are trying to revert to the previous selection.
Any idea about how could this be done?

I've created an implementation of `ItemListener` interface. Captured the previous value by checking for the `DESELECTED` event and validated the current selection after `SELECTED` event. But I'm not sure about where do I reset to the previous value when needed.

- Can I do it from the listener itself?
- Would that lead to recursive calls to my listener?

Comment: "Can I do it from the listener itself ? Would that lead to recursive calls to my listener ?" Only one way to find out...

Comment: I tried but failed. Figured I might be doing it wrong. Just wanted an affirmation.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I do it from the listener itself ?

Yes you can. For instance:

```
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

    Object previousSelection = null;

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

        if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) {                    
            previousSelection = e.getItem();                
        } else if(!isValid(e.getItem())) {
            JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
            cb.setSelectedItem(previousSelection);                
        }
    }
});
```

Where `isValid(Object obj)` method should validate selected item.

> Would that lead to recursive calls to my listener ?

Sure but the previous selected item was valid so it will be called 2 times top:

- First time when user attempts to select an invalid item.
- Second time when listener sets the previous item as the selected one.